# Facebook IOS SDK: Error in Publish Story Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I've successfully set up the "DemoApp" project from the [Facebook IOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to use my "OKC ThunderCast" Facebook application.  I have also configured another "Tester" application from scratch to successfully use the Facebook SDK and publish stories to my news feed.  However, in my production application, I **always** [get this result](http://www.okcthundercast.com/media/screenshot.png) when calling the "dialog" method.  The full description of the error message is "Error on line 52 at column 17: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 0 and body"

Here's a detailed walkthrough of all of my code to make sure nothing is missed.

1) A UIViewController calls the "authorize" method

```
NSArray *fbPerms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"offline_access", nil];
[[FacebookSingleton sharedInstance].facebook authorize:fbPerms delegate:self];
```

Note: The FacebookSingleton is a class I wrote that always returns a single instance of the "Facebook" class.  I am using it successfully in other applications.

2) Safari is opened and the user is successfully authenticated and authorized

3) The application is called back and the "handleOpenUrl" method is called, which calls the "fbDidLogin" method of the UIViewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
 {
Facebook *fb = [FacebookSingleton sharedInstance].facebook;
return [fb handleOpenURL:url];
 }
```

4) The same UIViewController handles the "fbDidLogin" event, and calls the "dialog" method

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
{   
[[FacebookSingleton sharedInstance].facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
   }
```

I also have the necessary "URL Schemes" and "URL Types" entries in the .plist file.  To my eyes, I am using exactly the same code in the "DemoApp", "Tester", and production applications.  But while the DemoApp and Tester work, I always see this HTML error in the feed dialog in my production application.  Has anyone seen a similar issue?  Could it be related to the Facebook "Bundle ID" setting in the Facebook application settings?  Is there some build or .plist setting that is different?

I have invested a great deal of time into troubleshooting with no success in several weeks.  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was setting a value to the key "User-Agent" in the NSUserDefaults dictionary.  I wanted to specify my own User-Agent to uniquely identify my iOS app.  But somehow setting this value caused the problem above.  When I simply renamed this key to "OKCTC-User-Agent" the error was immediately resolved.

I did log an [issue on the GitHub site for the Facebook-IOS-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/256).  Hopefully this will help others who have encountered similar problems.